# How to instantiate an object by variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

```
class Foo
end

class_name = 'Foo'
f = eval(class_name).new
#<Foo:0x007fd3e273ed68>
```

This example creates the expected instance of Foo.

The class is expected to be defined, but we want to instantiate an object of the class defined in `class_name`.

The value for `class_name` is coming from the user, so the above code is a Very Bad Idea™...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class is nothing special. It is just an object assigned to a variable, or in the case of the code you showed, a constant. So, you can use the same metaprogramming methods to retrieve a class from a variable as you would use with any other object: [`Object#instance_variable_get`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.2.0.preview1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get), [`Module#class_variable_get`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.2.0.preview1/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_get), [`Binding#local_variable_get`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.2.0.preview1/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get), [`Thread#thread_variable_get`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.2.0.preview1/Thread.html#method-i-thread_variable_get), or the one which is applicable in this case [`Module#const_get`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.2.0.preview1/Module.html#method-i-const_get):

```
class Foo; end

class_name = 'Foo'
foo = Object.const_get(class_name).new
#=> #<Foo:0x007fd3e273ed68>

foo = self.class.const_get(class_name).new
#=> #<Foo:0x007fd3e273ed68>
```

Note that the code in the other two answers only works accidentally: they look up `Foo` in the context of the `Module` class, which only works because you have *actually* defined `Foo` in `Object` and `Module` inherits from `Object`. If you had defined `Foo` not in an ancestor but in a sibling of `Module`, then the code in the other two answers wouldn't work:

```
module Bar; class Foo; end end

Module.const_get(:Foo)
# NameError: uninitialized constant Module::Foo

Bar.const_get(:Foo)
# => Bar::Foo
```

If you want `const_get` to behave the same way that normal constant lookup would, you need to call it on the class/module you want to actually look it up in, not on some random class.

Comment: Wow, this is the answer I was looking for. Thank you. Do you have any resources you recommend on Metaprogramming?

Comment: Ruby programmers don't tend to think of metaprogramming as anything special. It's just a natural part of normal programming to them, so typically they also don't think about writing special resources for it. Any resource for Ruby programming will also cover metaprogramming, even in the very beginning: `attr_accessor` is a method that generates methods, ergo everytime you use `attr_accessor`, you are doing metaprogramming. However, [_why the lucky stiff](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_the_lucky_stiff)'s writings, are ver good at explaining metaprogramming, if you can indulge his unique style.

Comment: See, for example, [*Why's (Poignant) Guide to Ruby*](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/), specifically [*Dwemthy's Array*](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/dwemthy/) (a dungeon game played using Ruby metaprogramming!) Plus, there's always the [*Metaprogramming Ruby* book by Paolo Perrotta](https://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr2/metaprogramming-ruby-2). However, I can't say anything about any of those resources, because I myself actually learned Ruby Metaprogramming simply through programming in Ruby, because it's just so natural to do.

Comment: Just discovered that one of my favorite resources has 2 interactive "books" on metaprogramming: https://rubymonk.com/learning/books

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`Module::const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get).

```
class Foo
end

class_name = 'Foo'
myClass = Module.const_get(class_name)
myClass.new
```

---

Of course, as the name implies, you can use this to get any kind of constant. So might be wise to check if you're getting a class back:

```
SOME_CONST = 5
Module.const_get('SOME_CONST').is_a? Class   # => false
Module.const_get('String').is_a? Class       # => true
```

Answer (score 1):

[`const_get`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_get) can get a reference to the Class

```
Module.const_get( :Foo ).new
```

or

```
Module.const_get( 'Foo' ).new
```

Note: in < 1.9 it only searches the current module.